# Deploy and host custom asp.net mvc applications in sharepoint 2016 intranet portal

Tags: authentication, sharepoint-hosted-app, provider-hosted-app, 2016

we have developed some applications in asp.net mvc and trying to access these applicatons as from one sharepoint  intranet portal that is for our organization
- How can we deploye these applicaton in sharepoint and and access throgh sharepoint portal what are the steps? and authentication will be single sign on once users login to sharepoint they will be access to asp.net mvc applications.

i read about as sharepoint hosted apps and provider hosted apps is these helpful?

Comment: What authentication model are you currently using? Did you trying accessing these MVC end points from SharePoint? Any errors? Please post your environment details to help you better.

Comment: Do you have the SharePoint Solution which you have deployed?

Comment: we have intranet portal in sharepoint 2010 and plan to move to sharepoint 2016

Comment: Not answered ??  Though Provider hosted apps is the way to go, but came here to see some complete flow, as OP (and of course me as well) need _some already deployed/hosted applications_ to be accessible from Sharepoint. Perhaps @adilahmed may have got a solution since then : )